# How do I get the container instance back from ServiceLocation?

Tags: castle-windsor, service-locator, common-service-locator

Is is possible to get the container instance back from ServiceLocation? I only see the ability to resolve instances of types, not register them.

Comment: solution is simple - don't use service locator and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. CommonServiceLocator only abstracts resolution, not registration. One of the reasons is that registration is wildly different for each particular container.

As Krzysztof commented, try to avoid service locator as much as possible. It might be necessary for some special cases to *resolve* something, but ***never to register***.